# MediaWiki Database: Why the incredibly long response time?

Tags: sql, database, time, mediawiki, wiki

I have been consolidating 3 Databases into one via prefixes in my mediawiki installation. I got three wikis using the same database like so:

```
en_interwiki
de_interwiki
es_interwiki
```

Everything works fine out of visitor perspective... but whenever a USER wants to post a new article or commit edits, the database takes up to 35 seconds to respond. This is unacceptable.

I activated debugging like so:

```
# Debugging:
$wgDBerrorLog = '/var/log/mediawiki/WikiDBerror.log';
$wgShowSQLErrors = true;
$wgDebugDumpSql  = true;
$wgDebugLogFile = '/var/log/mediawiki/WikiDebug.log';
$wgShowDBErrorBacktrace = true;
```

I am getting debug info, and it seems that `pagelinks` is the culprit, but i am not one hundred percent sure.

Did anyone ever have this issue before?

Please help me!

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it. In my case, the memcache had the wrong port. Everything is back to normal.

In case anyone uses memcache with their MediaWiki installation: Be sure to use the right port on your server, or you will end up like me, with 30 second-wait-times.